# Getting number of results of typeahead-input in meteor app

Tags: meteor, typeahead.js

I'm using typeahead with my meteor app using `sergeyt:typeahead`. I'm using multiple datasets:

**helper**

```
  Template.demo.helpers({
    teams: function() {
      return [
        {
          name: 'nba-teams',
          valueKey: 'name',
          local: function() { return Nba.find().fetch(); },
          header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>',
          template: 'team'
        },
        {
          name: 'nhl-teams',
          valueKey: 'name',
          local: function() { return Nhl.find().fetch(); },
          header: '<h3 class="league-name">NHL Teams</h3>',
          template: 'team'
        }
      ];
    }
  });
```

**Result template:**

```
<template name="team">
    <h4><i>{{name}}</i></h4>
</template>
```

Now I need to know e.g. for a submit-event of the form if there are results / how many results. But I don't find any informations how to do that.

Maybe I have to iterate over the elements in `.tt-menu` but this feels quite bad for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I assume, that the results are shown as li-elements. If it is something different in your template, you have to change `find()`

```
'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newElement = $('.tt-menu').find("li").length == 0,
    hasContent = event.target[1].value.length > 0;
    if (hasContent && newElement) {
        console.log('new element');
    }
    else { console.log($('.tt-menu').find("li").length); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`typeahead:render`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events) event for this. According to Twitter's typeahead.js documentation:

> The event handler will be invoked with 4 arguments: the jQuery event object, **the suggestions that were rendered**, a flag indicating whether the suggestions were fetched asynchronously, and the name of the dataset the rendering occurred in.

So you could just bind the event to your input:

```
Template.demo.onRendered(function () {
  this.$('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:render', function(ev, suggestions) {
    // may not be that simple to fetch, but inspect the object and you can figure it out
    console.log(suggestions.length); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this gives me an `undefined` for the first character and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` for the following input...